# How to store variable from program executed by batch file

Tags: batch-file

i am wondering how i could store a variable that is returned by a .exe program. My program is called getNumber.exe and it returns a numeric value.
Below i have posted my batch file. I know i need to check my errorlevel variable but i am unsure on how to go about this. It will allow me to enter a number but i am having trouble storing that returned number so i can utilize it within my batch file. Any ideas?

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal

for %%f in (%1) do (
 if exist "%%f" (
 echo 1: Open Notepad
 echo 2: Open in Word
 echo 3: Open in TextPad
 echo 4: Print
 getNum.exe
 echo %ERRORLEVEL%

 ) else (
   echo "%%f" not found please enter existing .txt file
  )
)

:end
```

Comment: Does it output as text to the console or does it have a return value?

Comment: the .exe only returns a value it does not do any output.

Comment: Hmm... And `%ErrorLevel%` is not resulting in the correct output? Try to add `EnableDelayedExpansion` after our `setlocal` (on the same line) and instead of `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` try `echo !ERRORLEVEL!`.

Comment: This worked perfectly... care to explain what the difference between %ERRORLEVEL% and !ERRORLEVEL! is?

Comment: Yup. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the so called `DelayedExpansion` on or two questions about this on StackOverflow as well...

The thing is that in batch a closed block of parenthesis is calculated at once when the first part is reached. This applies to for-loops as well as for if-statements.

To delay the calculation of the variable so you can use the value that got set within the same block there are two ways:

Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your code (usually beneath your `@echo off`) and if a variable is needed within such a block, that got set in the same block, instead of `%myVar%` you write `!myVar!`.

An alternative is using call with double `%`. This would then be something like `call echo %%myVar%%` although I think that the other way is safer.

Same thing applied to your script. `ERRORLEVEL` was set after executing `getNum.exe` and **within** the if.

Comment: what would i have to change in order to just use %ERRORLEVEL% just wondering.

Comment: Check the value after your last set of closed parenthesis where your value was set in. In your case check the value after the closing `)` of your for-loop.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%g in (getnum.exe) do (
 if "%%g"=="1" echo one on "%1"
 if "%%g"=="2" echo two
 ...etc
)
```

... oh -- so having claimed "it returns a numeric value" now we're told that it appears in `errorlevel`

```
if errorlevel 4 (echo 4 or more
) else (if errorlevel 3 echo three
) else (if errorlevel 2 echo two
) else (if errorlevel 1 echo one
))))
```